# node.js convert each line of a csv to sha1 and output to a new csv

Tags: node.js, csv, sha1

i'm kind of a newbie, so be gentle.  High level, I have a bunch of email address in a .csv.  I want to convert each email address into a sha1 for privacy purposes.  I'm attempting in node.js and here is what I have so far:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs');
var parse = require('csv-parse');
var async = require('async');

var inputFile = 'emailList.csv';
var outputFile = 'sha1List.csv';

var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1')

var parser = parse({delimiter: ','}, function (err, data) {
  async.eachSeries(data, function (line, callback) {
    // do something with the line
    hash.write(line).then(function() {
      // when processing finishes invoke the callback to move to the next one
      hash.end();
      callback();
    });
  })
})
fs.createReadStream(inputFile).pipe(parser).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(outputFile))    ;
```

However, my output file is zero bytes.  I'm pretty sure the problem is that the line object is a stream object and crypto doesn't work the way I implemented.  I also tried using the sha1 module as sha1(line).then(function etc etc etc.  Same result.  What should I do here?  Also, not married to node.js, if someone has a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i came up with https://gist.github.com/cdurth/6735c82cd11c5a057bd4

Not sure what your input csv looks like, so change the location of the email in the array accordingly